# Sides are smaller and one of diagonals is bigger. What happens to other diagonal?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

For any two point $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, denote the euclidean distance of $x$ and $y$ by $xy$. 
Let $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d'$ be eight points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some positive $n$. 
If $ab \le a'b'$, $bc \le b'c'$, $cd \le c'd'$, $da \le d'a'$, and $ac > a'c'$, then can we deduce that
$bd \le b'd'$?

Comment: Write down all possible triangle inequalities you can. One  combination might give the desired result.

Comment: @ Allawonder. I think u consider case $n=2$. But, I think ur sol may not work. For example, let $ab=bc=cd=da=a'b'=b'c'=c'd'=d'a'=2$, and $ac=bd=3$ and $a'c'=b'd'=2$. you may say this example is not possible, yes, but  triangle inequalities can't say this. I think maybe we need law of cosines. what do u think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The inequality $bd \le b'd'$ can fail.

To construct a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider following family of $4$-tuples of points:
$$\begin{cases}
A(t) = (t,0,0),\\
B(t) = (0,t,\sqrt{1-3t^2}),\\
C(t) = (-t,0,0),\\
D(t) = (0,-t,\sqrt{1-3t^2})
\end{cases}\quad\text{ for } t \in (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$$
It is easy to see
$$AB = BC = CD = DA = \sqrt{1-t^2}
\quad\text{ and }\quad AC = BD = 2t$$
As functions of $t$, $AB, BC, CD, DA$ is strictly decreasing while $AC$, $BD$ is strictly increasing.

Take $(a,b,c,d) = (A(t),B(t),C(t),D(t))$ and
$(a',b',c',d') = (A(t'),B(t'),C(t'),D(t'))$ for any $0 < t' < t < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, one find 
$$ab < a'b', bc < b'c', cd < c'd', da < d'a';\; ac > a'c'\quad\text{ but }\quad bd > b'd'$$

Comment: Thanks Dear Mr hui. Do u think the assertion holds if we consider more points? 
For example, if we consider 5 points instead of 4.
Generally, let $a_1,\ldots,a_k;a'_1,\ldots,a'_k$ be $2k$ points. 
Can we have, 
$a_{1} a_{1} \le a'_{1} a'_{2}, a_{2} a_{3} \le a'_{2} a'_{3}, \ldots, a_{k-1} a_{k} \le a'_{k-1} a'_{k}, a_{k} a_{1} \le a'_{k} a'_{1}$, and for all other pairs $ij$, $a_{i} a_{j} > a'_{i} a'_{j}$?

Comment: @user139975 hard to say, it is not clear to me whether this is possible or not. Even $k$ may be easier, one can start with a anti-prism, expanding the top/bottom face but shrinking the height to see whether it is possible to only reduce the distance of edges on the sides...

Comment: @user139975 When $k = 2m$ is even, it is possible. Let $\theta = \frac{\pi}{m}$. Let

$$a_i = \left(r\cos(i\theta), r\sin(i\theta), (-1)^i\frac{h}{2}\right)\quad\text{ for }\quad 1 \le i \le k$$
For $i \ne j$, we have
$$a_ia_j = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{2r^2(1-\cos((i-j)\theta)}, & i \equiv j \pmod 2\\
\sqrt{2r^2(1-\cos((i-j)\theta) + h^2}, & i \not\equiv j \pmod 2
\end{cases}$$
Since the factor $1 - \cos((i-j)\theta)$ gets larger as $j$ moves away from $i$. When we increase $r$ and decreases $h$, it is possible to increases all $a_ia_j$ except those satisfy $i \equiv j \pm 1 \pmod k$.

Comment: Thank u very much. Sorry I can't vote up your answer, I don't have the reputation.